# Why dont i need to Import A in Main?

Tags: java

```
   package A;

    public class A {


    }
```

---

```
package B;

import A.*;

public class B {

    public A a;
}
```

---

```
import B.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj = new B().a;
    }

}
```

Why don't i need to import class A in Main? It is at some point used in Main!

Can someone tell me how the import directive works exactly?

Answer (score 6):

It's not actually used in `Main`. At no point does `Main` refer to a class called `A` itself, any of its methods, or any of its fields. The compiler never needs to figure out that you typed `A` but really meant `A.A` - That's all the imports are for. `new B().a` might return an `A`, but `Main` doesn't care since it's immediately and implicitly cast to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Imports are using to remove ambiguity. For example if you have 2 B(`firstpackage.B` and `secondpackage.B`) classes in your project and you are writing something like:

```
B b = new B()
```

Java compiler should know which class(from first or second package) it should use.
But when you are calling instance of `B` class from other Class it's already defined and there is no ambiguity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

the Main class is never using an object of the Class A, therefore no import is neded, that you are using a Class B and B uses A, that is another thing. java takes cares of that when compiling so the dependencies are not nested, otherwise the main class muss import all what inside of their objects use/need

Comment: Actually the reference to A is resolved at runtime, not compile time. Minor point, but thought it was worth mentioning.